# How do I select an Android element using WebDriverIO?

Tags: android, cordova, appium, webdriver-io

I am using WebDriverIO/Appium/Mocha to perform automated testing on a Cordova Hybrid mobile application. i have the following XML of an element

```
<android.widget.Button index="0" text="Cancel" class="android.widget.Button" resource-id="android:id/button2" instance="0" />
```

i tried using the following code to select the element and perform a click

```
describe('Login Page', function() {
it('should allow user to login', function () {         
    var selector = 'new UiSelector().text("LOGIN")).className("android.widget.Button")';
    browser.click('android=' + selector);
    console.log("It's clicked");
}); 
});
```

i receive this error

[Android 6.0 #0-0] The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

i resorted to using its resourceid as an identifier. for more ways to identifying an element, refer to

[UIAUTOMATOR UISELECTOR][1]

```
browser.click('android=new UiSelector().resourceId("android:id/button1")');
```

you may even chain the methods to uniquely identify an element

```
browser.setValue('android=new UiSelector().text("User Name").className("android.widget.EditText")', 'user');
browser.setValue('android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.EditText").instance(1)', 'something');
```